# Time delay neural network in tensorflow and the meaning of convolutions

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I wondered if there was anyone who might spare a little time to help me with Time-delay neural networks?

As I understand it, each neuron is sensitive to part of the input through a particular number of time-steps. In my example, I have a 2D array of 31 amino acids in a sequence (time if you will). Each entry is a sparse encoded bitfield, 21 wide, with a true if its a particular acid, and false in all other entries.

As I understand it, I need to use a convolution. I need a kernel that is 1D in size. Taking the image analogy, I have a 1D image that, instead of having RGB channels, has 21 channels thus producing 21 feature maps. My convolution is 1 x time_window_size x 21. I.e, I have 21 neurons, each sensitive to a particular channel (in this case the presence of a particular amino acid).

The source code is here on git:
https://github.com/OniDaito/MRes/blob/master/nn01/nn01.py

I'm aware that LSTMs, dense encoding and the like will be better - I'd just like to start somewhere known and progress from there.

My question - is my assumption that a 1D convolution will result in a set of neurons with shared weights that are sensitive to order and a particular channel?

Cheers

Ben